# How to extract contents/tables below a heading/title from pdf using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I have different PDF files containing information in text, image and different table formats. Some PDF files have invisible lines for tables while others are in a proper table format. My goal is to identify a specific table based on title and extract it.

[image: Example of PDF Page]

The above pdf page consist of title and table under it. I want to extract all the tables under the title "GRI Standards Index" spanning across pages. How can I do it in python? Kindly help.